# Restricting options method in javalin

Tags: kotlin, embedded-jetty, rate-limiting, javalin

We have a kotlin code like the following, I am trying to disable the options method for the API's as follows using Javalin(3.12.0), but it is resulting in blocking all the other methods like get and post as well. What is that I am missing here?

```
val app = Javalin.create {
        it.defaultContentType = "application/json"
        it.enableWebjars()
        it.addStaticFiles("", Location.CLASSPATH)
        it.enableCorsForAllOrigins()
        it.dynamicGzip = true
    }

app.options("/*") {ctx -> ctx.status(405)}

app.routes {        
        path("/auth") {
             post("/login") {
                Auth.doLogin(it)
            }
             get("/metrics") {
                val results = getData()
                it.json(results)
            }     
         }
```

Also there are 2 questions
1.want to implement the ratelimit for the get APi's for 20 request for an hour using the below code

```
   app.get("/") { ctx ->
     RateLimit(ctx).requestPerTimeUnit(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // throws if rate limit is exceeded
     ctx.status("Hello, rate-limited World!")
   }
```

How to achieve it?

2. How to restrict the jetty server version to display when the API call is made?

Answer (score 2):

For Jetty...

There is only 1 Rate Limit concept in Jetty, and that's the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.AcceptRateLimit`, added as a Jetty Container LifeCycle bean to the `ServerConnector`, it cannot adjust rates for specific request endpoints, only for the entire connector.

If you want specific endpoint rates, then the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter` is the way that's done with Jetty.

The `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration` for the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector` contains the controls to enable/disable the server announcement.

See

- `HttpConfiguration.setSendServerVersion(boolean)`
- `HttpConfiguration.setSendXPoweredBy(boolean)`
- `HttpConfiguration.setSendDateHeader(boolean)`